# Stash just one file with GitExtension

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have sample SpringBoot application with just two classes, just for test the `manage stash` feature of Git Extensions 3.5.4.12724.

I know this question has been asked several times here and I have read a lot of response but none of these work.

So suppose we have a project with two file, and we stash both them. We'll have a view on *GitExtension* -> *Manage Stash* like follow:

[image]

Now if I wanted to add only the changes made to the file `DockerDemoApplication.java` (the first) and I select it and click on *Apply Selected Stash*, GitExtension applies the changes for all the files in the list.

Do I Stash my files in wrong way? Is not the `Manage Stash` the properly feature to do this job? Or is a bug of an older version?

Comment: you can inspect stash by running this command
`git stash show -p stash@{0}`
And then run the `git stash apply` command.

Comment: 'Apply selected stash' is applying all the changes on all the files contained in the stash and it is normal. You should right click on the file you want to apply the changes and you should have a menu to do it. You should even be able to do it from the diff view on the right and apply only part of changes in a file (right click also)

Comment: I think there is something misleading: "selected" doesn't have the same meaning in "Stash selected changes" (I guess you can select files and stash only these files ?) and in "Drop Selected Stash"/"Apply Selected Stash" (refers to a complete stash, which you can select in the drop down menu "Show: WIP on main ..."). As suggested by Philippe: right click on individual files, this is where I would look for actions that target one file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Apply selected stash' is applying all the changes on all the files contained in the stash and it is normal because normally you manage a stash as a whole and it is relatively rare to apply part of it.

You should right click on the file you want to apply the changes and you will have a menu with the menu item "Cherry pick file changes":

[image]

You could even apply only part of changes from a file from the diff view on the right and by selecting only the changes you want and choose "Stage selected line(s)" (or press the 'S' --like '**S**tage'-- key)  :

[image]